# Modis Reprojection Tool "Input header file, Error in module"

Tags: modis, hdf, modis-reprojection-tool

I am trying to run Modis Reprojection tool for conversion from HFD to Geotiff for Modis terra Level 2 data 3KM swath i.e "MOD04_3K". Every time I try to input a file I get the following error:
Error in module: ReadHdrFile"

Any suggestions what can be done in order to solve this problem.

[image: MRT Error in Module]

Comment: I met the same question with you. However, I found that when I copy the MODIS data into a folder with deep directory, this happens, but if I put them into another folder just under the first-level directory, this situation does not happen.

Answer (score 1):

At first glance, I'd expect the issue to be that you are trying to use the MODIS Reprojection Tool (which is designed for tiled and georeferenced data) and not the MODIS Reprojection Tool Swath (which is designed for the swath data).

When working with the swath data, it is a bit more complex, and you'll usually also need the geolocation file from the associated swath acquisition.